# How can i do database CRUD operations by taking parameters from aspx.cs file?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, database

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetValue3(id) {
        text1 = documnet.getElementById(input parameter from cs file);
        alert("this is from cs file");
        //database transactions here <-------method1
    }
    $(function () {
        button1 = document.getElementById(input parameter from aspx file);
        $("[id*=Button1]").on("click", function () {
            alert("this is from aspx file");
        //database transactions here <-------method2
        })
    })
</script>
```

My question is that there are two procedures for database transactions, first from taking parameters from aspx.cs code befind file and second from aspx file.

In my code i want to do database transactions using second approach (by using parameters from aspx.cs code behind) because it is required in my coding.

please guide me how can i build this approach.

Comment: please beware the code you shared is javascript-> meaning its executed on client. If you want to communicate with database from webform use code behind (executed on serverside) there is difference between server click event and click event.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to achieve but you need to differentiate between **client events and server events**

to get element in JS you can get its ID from 'ClientID'

ASPX file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest"  OnTextChanged="txtTest_TextChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btn1" OnClick="btn1_Click" runat="server" Text="Click" />
    
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function textFromTextBox() {
    var text1 = documnet.getElementById('<%= this.txtTest.ClientID %>');
  }
</script>
```

aspx cs file

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = txtTest.Text;
}

protected void txtTest_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var updatedText = txtTest.Text;            
}
```

EDIT:
you cannot attach code behind method to ordinary html element. You can only attach javascript events to these elements or inputs. If its the case then its irrelevant if you are using asp.net web forms, python, ruby on backend server.

```
<input type="button" id="sbutton" value="Save" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  (function (){
      documnet.getElementById('sbutton').addEventListener("click", function(){ //do your crud operation });;
  })
  ()

</script>
```

Comment: My control is written in aspx.cs code behind file like this: <input type = 'button' id='" + b1 + "' onclick=\"GetValue6('" + b1 + "')\" value='Save') />. And i have to implement it's click event in aspx file.

Comment: please update your original post. but from what i see there no point doing all of this on client side, especially with string concatenation

Comment: aspx.cs file:
string TextGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
<input type='text' id="TextGUID" value="vijay" />
<input type="button" id="sbutton" onclick=GetValue('" + TextGUID + "') value="Save" />

aspx file:
there is no textbox in aspx file.
In aspx file, there is a function:
function GetValue(id1){
//how can i code database CRUD operations here by using id1.click event
}

Comment: if i am declaring a button control in aspx.cs code behind file like: <input type="button" id="sbutton" onclick=GetValue('" + TextGUID + "') value="Save" />, then how can i code it's click event in aspx file.

Comment: you are mixing too many things,... strongly recomend to look for some tutorial and decide what you are really trying to do. i updated my answer above.